# Regular Expression remove [caption]

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to remove some html from my string of text which comes from a Wordpress generated database.

I want this:

```
Marnie Stanton led us through the process first and then everyone went crazy. 
[caption id="attachment_76" align="alignnone" width="191"] One of the work stations[/caption]
[caption id="attachment_78" align="alignnone" width="300"] The group is getting some great results[/caption]
[caption id="attachment_83" align="alignnone" width="224"] You can see the prints multiplying[/caption]
```

to turn into this:

```
Marnie Stanton led us through the process first and then everyone went crazy.
```

So what I want is everything from the first `[caption]` to the very last `[/caption]` to be removed.

I have started with this:

```
(\[caption\s+?[^]]+\])
```

Which only removes the first tag.

Comment: How about the `Anne surprises herself ...` text, should that be in the result?

Comment: Oh Actually no it shouldn't be, but that is just an issue with how this was added to the wordpress blog, so for all purposes with writing the regular expression, it should still be there.

Comment: I removed it from the question so there's no more confusion, also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to use something like this

```
$string = 'Marnie Stanton led us through the process first and then everyone went crazy. 
[caption id="attachment_76" align="alignnone" width="191"] One of the work stations[/caption]
[caption id="attachment_78" align="alignnone" width="300"] The group is getting some great results[/caption]
I want to keep this !
[caption id="attachment_83" align="alignnone" width="224"] You can see the prints multiplying[/caption]';

$new_string = preg_replace('#\s*\[caption[^]]*\].*?\[/caption\]\s*#is', '', $string);
echo $new_string;
```

**Output:**

> Marnie Stanton led us through the process first and then everyone went crazy.I want to keep this !

**Explanation:**

- Modifiers `is` : `i` means match case insensitive, `s` means match new lines with dots `.`
- `\s*` : match white spaces 0 or more times
- `\[caption` : match `[caption`
- `[^]]*` : match anything except `]` 0 or more times
- `\]` : match `]`
- `.*?\[/caption\]` : match anything until `[/caption]` found (and match `[/caption]`)
- `\s*` : match white spaces 0 or more times

[**Online demo**](http://codepad.org/YZwJKUcR)

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you just want the start of the string, I would not use a regular expression but string functions:

```
$pos = stripos($your_string, '[caption');
$result = substr($your_string, 0, $pos);
```

Comment: That would be one solution to this particular case, however the issue is with this being a wordpress site the admin may choose to put the body of text that needs to be shown at the end of the captions rather than the beginning. I just want to remove the captions any where they are.

Comment: @DylanCross That's why I asked about the text that was initially between the captions...

Comment: Oh sorry, my comment must have been misunderstood then. But that was my fault.

Answer (score 1):

[caption] is an example of a [shortcode](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/shortcodes/). You can remove all shortcodes with Wordpress' `strip_shortcodes();` function.

```
$text = 'Marnie Stanton led us through the process first and then everyone went crazy. 
[caption id="attachment_76" align="alignnone" width="191"] One of the work stations[/caption]
[caption id="attachment_78" align="alignnone" width="300"] The group is getting some great results[/caption]
I want to keep this !
[caption id="attachment_83" align="alignnone" width="224"] You can see the prints multiplying[/caption]';

$text = strip_shortcodes($text);
echo $text;
```

This will output:

> Marnie Stanton led us through the process first and then everyone went crazy.I want to keep this !

---

[[caption] documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode)

[strip_shortcodes documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can explode the string by newlines, and just take the first line...

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOD
Marnie Stanton led us through the process first and then everyone went crazy.
[caption id="attachment_76" align="alignnone" width="191"] One of the work stations[/caption]
[caption id="attachment_78" align="alignnone" width="300"] The group is getting some great results[/caption]
[caption id="attachment_83" align="alignnone" width="224"] You can see the prints multiplying[/caption]
EOD;

$lines = explode("\n", trim($str));

echo $lines[0]; # Marnie Stanton led us through the process first and then everyone went crazy.
```